# Using array.exists() in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to Scala and functional programming. I'm creating a tic-tac-toe game (Day 1 of 'Seven Languages in Seven Weeks' (book)) and I'd like to know how to do 'check if won' method in a functional way.

I want to make the 'checkrow' part (first part) like the 'checkcolumn' (second part) part, but what I'm trying is not working.

Here my (working) code:

```
def checkGame() {
    for (y <- board.indices) {
      // checks a row
      checkRow(y)
    }
    for (x <- board(0).indices) {
      // checks a column
      if(!board.exists(y => y(x) != 'x')){
        println("You have won mate! (column: " + x + ")")
      }
    }
  }

def checkRow(y: Integer) {
var isWon = true
for (x <- board(y).indices) {

  if (board(y)(x) != 'x') {
    isWon = false
  }
}
if (isWon) println("You have won mate! (row: " + y + ")")
}
```

Note: board is a 2 dimensional array.

What I got so far (doesn't work):

```
if(!board.exists(x => x(y) != 'x')){
        println("You have won mate! (row: " + x + ")")
}
```

Comment: You're not doing it "in a functional way" if you're using `for` lopps and variable mutations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of having higher-order functions such as `exists` is to avoid having to traverse your `Array` using indices.

Here is how I'd do it:

```
def wonRow(row: Array[Char]): Boolean = row.forall(c => c == 'x')
```

This uses the `forall` method, that checks if ALL the elements of the array satisfy the predicate (here, all the elements must be `'x'`).

```
def wonSomeRow(board: Array[Array[Char]]: Boolean = board.exists(row => wonRow(row))
```

Here, we consider that some row makes a win if ANY element of the array (so any row) satisfies the predicate (here, to be a winning row)

For columns, this is somehow more intricate, so the easiest way is to do as you started:

```
def wonColumn(board: Array[Array[Char]], col: Int) = board.forall(row => row(i) == 'x')

def wonSomeColumn(board: Array[Array[Char]]) = (0 until board(0).size).exists(i => wonColumn(board, i))
```

However, I would strongly suggest that you replace `board(0).size` by some constant at the top of your code, to avoid getting some error. Indeed, this assumes that

- 1) `board` has a first row
- 2) all row in `board` have at list size `board(0).size`

Of course, these two assumptions are ok in a Tic-Tac-Toe, but in functional programming, such compile-time assumptions should rather be put in the type system, to be verified at compile time. However, this would make quite a step to start functional programming with this kind of things (just know that they exist).

**EDIT**

I just remembered there is a method `transpose` on arrays, so you can just do (for columns)

```
def wonSomeCol(board: Array[Array[Char]]) = wonSomeRow(board.transpose)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well... one functional approach can be the use of `foldLeft`. Here you start with two `Set`s of `Int`, each for winRows and winColumns with all rows and columns.

Then, you fold over the gameboard to eliminate the `rows` and `columns` which do not satisfy the victory condition.

```
def findVictoryRowsAndColumns(board: Array[Array[Char]], height: Int, width: Int): (Set[Int], Set[Int])  = {
  val winRowsInit = (1 to height).toSet
  val winColumnsInit = (1 to width).toSet

  val (winRows, winColumns) = board.zipWithIndex.foldLeft((winRowsInit, winColumnsInit))({
    case ((winRows1, winColumns1), (row, rowIndex)) => row.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(winRows1, winColumns1)({
      case ((winRows2, winColumns2), (cell, columnIndex)) => cell match {
        case 'x' => (winRows2, winColumns2)
        case _ => (winRows2 - rowIndex, winColumns2 - columnIndex)
      }
    })
  })

  (winRows, winColumns)
}

def checkGame(board: Array[Array[Char]], height: Int, width: Int): Unit = {
  val (winRows, winColumns) = findVictoryRowsAndColumns(board, height, width)

  winRows.foreach(i => println("You have won in Row : " + i))
  winColumns.foreach(i => println("You have won in Column : " + i))
}
```